# How to pass variables from jquery form into a hosted paypal button

Tags: jquery, paypal, form-submit

Hi have worked several days to created this form for a website, and I'm stuck at the final step which is to pass on the user imputed variables into a PayPal "buy now" button.

HERE is a live demo of how the form currently looks like.

[DEMO](http://unlock4mobile.com/wp-content/themes/kassyopea/raunch.html)

I need the paypal button to show up the last page of the form. I have just started programming and am not familiar with more advanced methods such as using the paypal api. I want the use simple solution possible. Can someone please lead me to the best way to do this.

**The HTML is as follows:**

```
<div id="container">
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <!-- #first_step -->
        <div id="first_step">
             <h1>SELECT THE <span>PROVIDER</span> THE PHONE IS LOCKED TO</h1>

            <div class="form">
                <select id="provider" class="chzn-select" name="provider" data-placeholder="Click Here To Select">
                    <option value="0">Please Select A Provider</option>
                </select>
                <label for="provider">The company the phone is CURRENTLY locked to, not the company you wish to use afterwards.</label>
            </div>
            <!-- clearfix -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!-- /clearfix -->
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="" />
        </div>
        <!-- clearfix -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- /clearfix -->
        <!-- #second_step -->
        <div id="second_step">
             <h1>ENTER THE <span>MODEL</span> OF YOUR PHONE</h1>

            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" name="model" id="model" value="" />
                <label for="model">Enter the exact model of your phone (ex: Samsung Galaxy S4 sgh-i337)</label>
            </div>
            <!-- clearfix -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!-- /clearfix -->
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
        </div>
        <!-- clearfix -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- /clearfix -->
        <!-- #third_step -->
        <div id="third_step">
             <h1>ENTER THE <span>SERIAL NUMBER</span> OF YOUR PHONE</h1>

            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" maxlength="15" name="os1" id="imei" value="imei" />
                <label for="model">Enter the 15 digit IMEI number of your phone. The best way to find this number is to dial *#06# on your phone as if making a call</label>
            </div>
            <!-- clearfix -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!-- /clearfix -->
            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_third" id="submit_third" value="" />
        </div>
        <!-- clearfix -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- /clearfix -->
        <!-- #fourth_step -->
        <div id="fourth_step">

<h1>CONFIRM THAT ALL INFORMATION IS <span>CORRECT</span> </h1>

            <div class="form">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>provider</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>model</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>imei</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- clearfix -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!-- /clearfix -->
            <input class="send submit" type="submit" name="submit_fourth" id="submit_fourth" value="" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

**THE JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(function () {
    //original field values
    var field_values = {
        //id        :  value
        'provider': 'provider',
            'model': 'model',
            'imei': 'imei',

    };


    //inputfocus
    $('input#provider').inputfocus({
        value: field_values['provider']
    });
    $('input#model').inputfocus({
        value: field_values['model']
    });
    $('input#imei').inputfocus({
        value: field_values['imei']
    });
    $('input#email').inputfocus({
        value: field_values['email']
    });




    // ========== FIRST STEP START ===============
    $('form').submit(function () {
        return false;
    });
    $('#submit_first').click(function () {
        //remove classes
        $('#first_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

        //ckeck if inputs aren't empty
        if ($('#provider').val() == "0") {
            $('#country').addClass('error');
            alert("You must slect the PROVIDER your phone is locked to first.");
        } else {
            //slide steps
            $('#first_step').slideUp();
            $('#second_step').slideDown()
        }
    });
    // ========== FIRST STEP END ===============

    // ========== Second STEP START ===============
    $('#submit_second').click(function () {
        //remove classes
        $('#second_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');


        // check if model feild is filled out

        if ($('#model').val().length <= 1) {
            alert("Must fill out the model of your phone");
            $('#model').addClass('error');
            $('#model').effect("shake", {
                times: 3
            }, 50);
        } else {
            //slide steps
            $('#second_step').slideUp();
            $('#third_step').slideDown();
        }


    });
    // ========== Second STEP END ===============



    // ========================= THIRD STEP START =============================
    $('#submit_third').click(function () {


        //prepare the fourth step
        var fields = new Array(
        $('#provider option:selected').text(),
        $('#model').val(),
        $('#imei').val());


        var tr = $('#fourth_step tr');
        tr.each(function () {
            //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
            $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
        });

        // ======= check if imei # is valid BEGIN ================
        if ($('#imei').val().length != 15) {
            alert("IMEI number must be exactly 15 digits");
            $('#imei').addClass('error');
            $('#imei').effect("shake", {
                times: 3
            }, 50);
        } else if (isNaN($('#imei').val())) {
            alert("IMEI number must be only numbers! (no spaces or periods)");
            $('#imei').addClass('error');
            $('#imei').effect("shake", {
                times: 3
            }, 50);
        }
        // ======= check if imei # is valid END ================

        else {
            //slide steps
            $('#third_step').slideUp();
            $('#fourth_step').slideDown();


            // ========================== THIRD STEP END =========================
            // ========================= FOURTH STEP START =============================

            $('#submit_fourth').click(function () {
                //send

                alert('Data sent');
            });

        });
```

---

**THE PAYPAL BUTTON HTML CODE IS:**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxxxxxxx">

<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="model"> 
<input type"hidden" name="os0">

<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="imei">
<input type="hidden" name="os1" ></td></tr>

<input type="hidden" name="on2" value="provider">
<input type="hidden" name="os2">

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"    border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"> 
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your jQuery action to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr and add hidden inputs there? Then on the fourth where it says Data sent make it submit the form? (return true)

Comment: are you able to provide the code? am not sure how to approach this.